# I want to set condition on filter that only login user data is load or public data will load. But private data will also be loaded

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Here is my query:

```
$maps = Mapdata::where('userid', Auth::user()->id)->ORwhere('public', 1)->whereBetween('from', array($request->from, $request->to))->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Let your controller do the check. Presuming that you need data that matches the logged-in user if he is logged & else case the public data. Try the following:

```
if(Auth::id()) {
  $maps = Mapdata::where('userid', Auth::id())->whereBetween('from', array($request->from, $request->to))->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
} else {
  $maps = Mapdata::where('public', 1)->whereBetween('from', array($request->from, $request->to))->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
}
```

Note: I don't have a clear idea of your DB & model structure. Please update your question with the same for a precise answer from me or someone else out here.

Comment: Sir when I apply one more filter like ->orWhereBetween('to', array($request->from, $request->to)) It will again show private data to0

Comment: That's a case of how you structure your SQL queries. Having an orWhere query will cause such an error, cause DB will return data that either matches your first condition or the second condition. So try using having query instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `when` method to write more clear code:

`where` method gets 3 parameters `boolean` to check, `callback1` executed if `boolean` is true and `callback2` executed if `boolean` is false.

In your case it will be:

```php
$maps = Mapdata::query()
  ->when(Auth::check(), function($q){
    $q->where(function($q){
      $q->where('userid', Auth::user()->id)->orWhere('public', 1);
    });
  }, function($q){
    $q->where('public', 1);
  })
  ->whereBetween('from', array($request->from, $request->to))
  ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

Generated sql:
When Authed: `SELECT * FROM mapdata WHERE (userid = ? OR public = 1) AND ...`

When Guest: `SELECT * FROM mapdata WHERE public = 1 AND ...`

Comment: Sir when I apply one more filter like                                                                                        ->orWhereBetween('to', array($request->from, $request->to))   It will again show private data to0

Answer (score 0):

Solved by this query.

$q->where('userid', Auth::user()->id)->orWhere('public', 1);
})->where(function($q) use ($request) {
$q->whereBetween('from', array($request->from, $request->to))->orWhereBetween('to', array($request->from, $request->to));
})->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();